# Web Socket In Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I am trying to use web socket.....

So this is my App\Events\TestEvent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

use App\Models\User;

class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $user;
    public $d;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = 1;
        $this->d = User::find($this->user);
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        // return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
        return ['testevent'];
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['data' => 1];
    }
}
```

And This is my App\Listener\TestListener

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

use App\Events\TestEvent;
use App\Models\User;

class TestListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  object  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(TestEvent $event)
    {
        $userID = $event->user;
        $user_details = User::find($userID);
    }
}
```

While Hitting The URL i am broadcasting this event as

```
broadcast(new TestEvent());
```

And Here i am showing in front-end side like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.Echo.channel('testevent').listen('TestEvent', function (e) {
            console.log('Event received:');
            // $('#gg').text(data);
        });
        
    </script>
```

When i hit the URL event is being register by web socket and in connection is being made and in every 30 seconds it auto getting the data.... but as in response of web socket i am expecting data but data key is coming empty.
the response is coming as

"
{event: "pusher:ping", data: {}}
data
:
{}
event
:
"pusher:ping"
"

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
  let channel = window.Echo.join("testevent");
  channel.listen("TestEvent", ({ data }) => {
        console.log(data);
  });
```

Inside the TestEvent class, add something like this:

```
 public function broadcastOn()
 {
    return new PresenceChannel('testevent');
 }
```

Brodcasting like this.

```
 broadcast(new TestEvent())->toOthers();
```

Comment: nope this is not working and i also need to put channel as Public